# GtkFileChooserButton 'Select Folder' mode returns no path

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, glade

I have added a GtkFileChooserButton to my app via Glade. It is set to folder selection mode. When the widget is clicked it shows a dropdown list of Nautilus bookmarks with an 'other' option in the end. A new file chooser dialog is launched when 'other' is clicked. The button is not connected to any other custom file chooser dialog.

The connecting signal I am using is 'file-set' and I am retrieving the fullpath of user selected folder using Gtk.FileChooser.get_current_folder ().

This setup works fine if user selects a folder from 'other' option. But if a user selects a bookmark from dropdown list, no path is returned. How to solve this?

Is there a way to disable this dropdown list and directly go to the filechooser dialog? I want to use GtkFileChooserButton only so that the user can get a preview of his selected folder.

Answer (score 2):

Because the file-set signal is only sent when the user *changes* the file, you will need to actually do the get_current_folder() call when you need to know the path, and not when the file-set signal is called. From the [documentation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserButton.html#GtkFileChooserButton-file-set), I see no way to get a notification when the user selects a path from the bookmarks, in folder selection mode.

As an alternative, though, you could use the FileChooserButton in normal mode, and simply use `get_current_folder` when the `file-set` signal is sent. This should give you the directory which the user is in, when a file is selected. Unfortunately, the UI will also look weird in this case, as the button will show the filename, while you're actually using the directory.

Also, you should probably file a bug against upstream GTK+ about this use case and how it isn't usable. The file-set signal really should be deprecated and renamed to path-set, and used in both modes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately, a custom dialog attached to filechooserbutton also shows dropdown bookmarks. I wonder why dropdown bookmarks are always turned on when there is no signal for them. How are we supposed to capture user input?

Comment: Sorry. After re-reading the docs, it does appear that suggestion wouldn't work, so I've updated my answer with an alternate alternative solution, which should definitely work, but will have seemingly broken UI due to the behavior.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion. I have solved the problem by using two widgets, a GtkEntry and a GtkButton. GtkButton is set on FileChooser 'folder select' mode. I retrieve user choice by using get_current_folder() and then set text to GtkEntry widget using set_text(). Not as elegant as FileChooserButton but it works. Here --> http://imgur.com/FMRIL

Comment: Ah, yes, that is also doable. Also, you could make a custom button widget that looks like a FileChooserButton, and does what you need. It would be very easy to do.

Answer (score 2):

I used the `current_folder_changed` signal inherited from `GtkFileChooser` and it seems to work even with the bookmarks.

Comment: This signal is also emitted when folders are changed while navigating the dialog, and before the chosen folder is accepted. Not desirable.

Comment: I think at the moment it's the best solution / workaround.

Answer (score 1):

GtkFileChooserButton in Folder Select mode can return the folder URI. Use `urlparse` module to convert URI to path. This works even with bookmarks. Hope this solves your issue.

```
import urlparse

folder_uri = filechooserbutton_meas.get_uri()
folder = urlparse.urlparse(folder_uri).path
```

Answer (score 0):

> This setup works fine if user selects a folder from 'other' option. But if a user selects a bookmark from dropdown list, no path is returned. How to solve this?

With GtkFileChooserButton, 'folder selection' mode.
The following code is good enough:

```
def on_mybutton_selection_changed(self, w):
   print "selected folder: ", w.get_file().get_path()
```

We get directory path on every selection of the dropdown menu, even bookmarks.

> I used the current_folder_changed signal inherited from GtkFileChooser and it seems to work even with the bookmarks.

Caution with w.get_current_folder(). It returns the LAST selected folder when user chose a folder from 'other' option, not the selected folder in the dropdown menu.